# Helm charts and Ingress resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I'm pretty new to K8s.

I'm trying to make my app visible to the outside world. I have deployed [this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/#configuration) Nginx Ingress Controller with my apps, using Helm and [helmfile](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile) which has given me an external ip address and a load balancer.

As I understand it, I now need an `ingress resource` to configure the route mappings.

I plan on using this ingress resource as a starting point.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

My apps are deployed in separate namespaces on port 80.

My question is: where do I put the yaml for creating the resources?

I want to keep everything in Helm if possible to make managing the configuration easier, so I don't want to use `kubectl` unless i have to.

### My helmfile

```
repositories:
 
- name: stable
  url: https://charts.helm.sh/stable
- name: nginx-stable
  url: https://helm.nginx.com/stable

releases:

  # other apps configured here

  - name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress
    createNamespace: true
    chart: nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
    values:
      - ./ingress/values.yaml
    version: 0.10.4
    installed: true
```

### My Ingress Controller values.yaml:

```
---
rbac:
  create: true

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: nginx-ingress-public

controller:
  ingressClassResource:
    enabled: true
    default: true

  replicaCount: 3
  minAvailable: 3
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 3
      maxUnavailable: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a step by step guide for using Ingress.

### Full source code [here](https://github.com/akhanalcs/k8s-hands-on).

### Step 1: Create helm chart

```
helm create test-app-api
```

### Step 2: Install Ingress controller

This command takes care of installing it. [Reference](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

A pod will be deployed which you can check:

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx get pod -o yaml
```

The information you need from this controller is `ingressClassName` which you'll put it in your `values.yaml` file, which will eventually make it to `ingress.yaml` file.

Find the `ingressClassName` of your controller by either running this command: `kubectl get ingressclasses` or finding it through K8s dashboard.

**Command way:**
[image]

**Dashboard way:**
[image]

### Step 3: Update ingress section in `values.yaml`

```
test-app-api: 
  # Other settings ...
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    className: nginx   # <--- ADD THIS GUY
    annotations:
      # Reference: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    hosts:
      - host: chart-example.local
        paths:
          - path: /my-test-app(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  # Other settings...
```

### Step 4: Deploy

```
helm upgrade --install test-app-release . \
--namespace=local \
--set test-app-api.image.tag="0.1.0" \
--create-namespace \
--debug \
--dry-run
```

Do a dry run to inspect the manifest and if everything looks good, run the command without the `--dry-run` flag.

### Step 5: Update hosts file

Check the ingress you deployed to see what address was assigned to your host because you'll be using that address to update your hosts file.

```
kubectl get ingress -n local
```

[image]

Also seen in controller logs:

```
W1119 05:14:31.194021       7 controller.go:1214] Service "local/test-app-release-test-app-api" does not have any active Endpoint.
I1119 05:15:19.437846       7 status.go:304] "updating Ingress status" namespace="local" ingress="test-app-release-test-app-api" currentValue=null newValue=[{"hostname":"localhost"}]
```

Now add this mapping to hosts file. (I'm on a mac and using vim to edit the hosts file.)

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Enter the server IP address at the bottom of the hosts file, followed by a space, and then the domain name.

[image]

Save and exit with `:wq`.

### Step 6: Test the app

Now, you should be able to reach the app from outside the cluster.
For eg:
http://chart-example.local/my-test-app/weatherforecast

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You should deploy the ingress controller only once as it can handle *all* ingress traffic for your whole cluster.

Sometimes it makes sense to deploy multiple, for example we run 2 ingress controller. 1 for internal traffic (private IP) and one for external traffic (public IP).

Once you have that, you just tell your other helm releases to use its ingress class.

The ingress manifest is usually a template of your helm chart. So you put it in templates. If you do `helm create my-app`, you get a good starting point, including ingress.

Once you have an ingress template in your chart, you can add some reasonable defaults for this template to the values.yaml of the chart, as usual.

When deploying the chart, you can use certain flags to override the defaults. i.e. `-f` and `--set`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have used `helm create my-app` and can see the ingress file, however it looks very "templatey". Can I just hardcode the values in there, or does it pick up the values from somewhere else (I appreciate this has turned into a "how do templates work" question. For example, can i put the values in the helmfile, to pass to the chart... to pass to the ingress.yaml file.

Comment: @WhatTheWhat, I am assuming that your app is already deployed via helm chart.  Maybe this helps https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/

Comment: yes it is, deployed and works fine. I can access it locally using port forwarding. I use helmfile to sync local changes to the cluster. Sorry but i don't see how the link helps, I still can't see where I put the ingress resource values

Comment: according to this: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files i can put them directly in the `values.yaml` for the ingress template to pick up?

Comment: @WhatTheWhat, yes, the values files is there to set the default values used by the templates in your templates directory.  You can override these with the -f or --set flags when installing the chart.

Comment: If you want to include that in your answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @WhatTheWhat, I have added this info.

Comment: One thing that i'm not clear on: if i define ingress values (ingress resource) for one of my apps, does that apply to other apps? For example, I want to route everything on `/` to a specific app. If i define that in one app, how does the other app know about it?

Comment: also i can't find `ingressClassName` in the template file. This seems really hard!

Comment: @WhatTheWhat, its a template. You can adjust it to your needs. For example adding the ingressClassName key. Regarding your question about routing, the apps dont know about each other but your ingress controller does. It knows all the ingress resources in your cluster and does its routing based on those.